# Why my files in public folder gets 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a file structure like this:

```
ng
    |---- controllers
    |         |----homeController.js
    |---- modules.js
node-modules
    |---- some modules here...
public
    |---- css
    |        |---main.css
    |---- js
    |        |---main.js
views
    |---- index.html.ejs
package.json
server.js
```

Here is my server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var ejs = require('ejs');

var app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
app.set('view-engine', ejs)

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html.ejs');
});

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    console.log('server is listening on Port: %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Now, In my index.html.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Mailer</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="addressBookApp">

    <h1>Sample Angular App </h1>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="ng/modules.js"></script>
    <script src="ng/controllers/homeController.js"></script>    
</body>

</html>
```

How can I resolve ng folder so that I can reference my angular module and controllers?

Also, As if I run this server then I get error:

Why any files in public folder is not loaded?
I get 404 for main.js and main.css

Comment: app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html.ejs');
}); You need to tell your server to always return your index.html.ejs, the routing is handled client side

Comment: You should make `ng` public

Comment: @AndrewDonovan I don't understand you

Comment: @Vishal you need to add '\*' after your '/', on the 10th line of code in your example. So when you type in the address bar your_ip/something it will work, otherwise it wont. You gave your server the instruction to serve your index file ONLY on '/', the '/*' allows for all routes.

Comment: @AndrewDonovan If I add `*` after `/` in my code then I get another error for css : `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html`. And for js files I get `Unexpected Token <` errors

Comment: @AndrewDonovan Got js and css running by including a `/` before public in app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));

Comment: @Vishal does the rest work ?

Comment: Yes rest works by following the answer by @SirwanAfifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serve files in `ng` directory you should make it public too:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/ng'));
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the `ng` directory:

```
http://localhost:3000/ng/controllers/homeController.js
```

By the way it's better to create a folder called `app` and put everything inside `ng` in this directory.

Comment: and what about css and js?

Comment: They are already defined as public: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));`

Comment: But I get 404 for them as well

Comment: Check the answer now, you must put `/` before directory name. @Vishal

Comment: Thanks. Now it works perfectly fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why should I create a folder named app? Also the files in public and ng may not conflict if they have same names? Is there any workaround for that? Also, Is my project structure good or should I make some changes?

Comment: Actually it's your choice, I always prefer to put angular related files inside public folder as a app folder. because they're also public.

Comment: Thanks for your support and time.